# AWS amplify UI admin failed to sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am using AWS amplify and AWS AppSync and DynamoDB.

after initing AWS amplify and I tested CRUD (create, read, update, delete).

It works well, and I can check DB at DynamoDB console.

And I found Admin UI services in AWS amplify console

So I deployed 'Content' in AWS amplify to see my DB table in Admin UI services.

But It failed to sync DB table, and I can see new element I create after deploying admin UI.

What should I do to see DB table created before deploying Admin UI service?

[image]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm having the same problem. "18 posts failed to sync"